# WPF WindowsFormsHost Winform user control shows but does not function

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to migrate an existing Winforms project into WPF. However: there are some user controls I need to leave as WinForm controls.

I have added a WinForms UserControl into a WPF Window. It consists of a RichTextBox and some buttons and labels. This is subclassed into various further user controls.

When I embed the UserControl into a WPF window it renders - but none of the buttons appear to do anything. When underlying processes update e.g. the RichTextBox it does not display the content. Yet when I inspect the textbox in debug I can see the content (though I have to click on 'base' to see this.)

[ One difference I have spotted - though it may not be relevant - is that when this control is on a WPF and non-working Visual Studio shows the object as 'sealed' but when in the original Winforms project when it is fully working it does not show as sealed. ]

I have added code to change the text in the labels - and they also firmly refuse to update: yet again I can see the text if I examine the label in debug mode.

This stack overflow question may address the same issue:
[WindowsFormsHost Winform pdfviewer control problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030306/windowsformshost-winform-pdfviewer-control-problem)

but the answer didn't make a lot of sense to me:
It mentioned replacing

```
new Window { Content = CreateContent(), Title = title }.Show();
```

But this is not a piece of code I recognise: I am using a xaml file with code behind and it's called up using

```
System.Windows.Application app = new System.Windows.Application(); 
app.Run(new FormWPFApp());
```

(where FormWPFApp is my name for the WPF window)

Here is the xaml header:-

```
<Window x:Class="ZedApp.FormWPFApp"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Printers="clr-namespace:ZedApp.UserControls.Printers"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"

        Title="Conversion version" Height="661" Width="1559" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

Here is the xaml I use for the two UserControls (they both inherit from the same base class) :-

```
<WindowsFormsHost Height="430" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,32,0,0" Name="windowsFormsHostTicketPrinter" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="324" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <Printers:TicketPrinter x:Name="ticketPrinter">
    </Printers:TicketPrinter>
</WindowsFormsHost>
<WindowsFormsHost Height="430" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="522,32,0,0" Name="windowsFormsHostJournalPrinter" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="324" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <Printers:JournalPrinter x:Name="journalPrinter">
    </Printers:JournalPrinter>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

[Another thing I have noticed is a method that clears the Rich Text Box on one of the windows starts kicking out errors of the following type if run under WindowsFormsHost in WPF -
"Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created."

```
private void ClearRichTextBox(RichTextBox rtbToClear)
{
    if (rtbToClear.IsHandleCreated)
    {

        if (rtbToClear.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<RichTextBox>(ClearRichTextBox), new object[] {rtbToClear});
            return;
        }

        rtbToClear.Clear();
    }
}
```

]

What is the likely cause of this behaviour and what do I need to do to get the elements within the User Control working?

Answer (score 0):

Proper input interop with WinForms requires some cooperation between the host and the WPF input system. The [topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348549.aspx)  Message Loops Between Win32 and WPF  in the SDK explains this well.  In your setup, the easiest way to make this happen is to use code like this:

```
Window w = new Window1();
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(w);
w.Show();
```

ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop() essentially registers an input hook with the WinForms Application object (which normally runs the message loop) and calls ComponentDispatcher.RaiseThreadMessage().

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a go - didn't seem to make any difference unfortunately. Are there other messaging interops I could/should apply also?